# Ordering/Parsing Heterogeneous CSV separated text values in a MySQL row-field

Tags: php, mysql, regex, perl, csv

I have a dataset resembling the following - I am very rusty on regex and have no knowledge of 'walking the tree' despite several meagre attempts - Text to Cols in Excel doesn't help due to the asinine organization of the various term classes/tags in the EFFECT_DATA field and the error introduced by manually adjusting.

#### SAMPLE DATA

```
ROW_ID|NAME   | UNORDERED_CSV_CONCATD_TAG_DATA_STRING

123456|Prod123|"Minoxidistuff [MoA], Direct [PE], Agonists [EPC]"
123457|Prod124|"Minoxion [Chem], InterferonA [EPC], Delayed [PE]"

123458|Prod125|"Anotherion [EPC], Direct [MoA], Agonists [EPC]"
123459|Prod126|"Competitor [PE], Progestin [EPC], Agonists [EPC]"
123460|Prod127|"Minoxidistuff [Chem]"
```

#### Sample desired Data output:

```
PRODUCT|EPC      |
Prod125|Antherion|
Prod125|Agonists |

PRODUCT|CMPD         |
Prod127|Minoxidistuff|
Prod124|Minoxion    |
```

etc for all the tags of product[i]tag[j] if that makes sense, essentially ea. CSVD_TAG_DATA field is out of order and contains multiple tags (at the end of the desired terms.

I am starting just a multi-dimensional hash approach ie excuse my butchered regex pseudocode.

Thanks much.

Comment: If it's well-formed then explode() is probably fine.

Comment: @GordonM - It's not well formed at least with respect to how the fields are ordered within the cell, I can see how explode([PE],$str) might work but and I am certain I can figure that out - more interested in walking the string into repetitive rows IE: Field X, Val ZYA, Field X Val 414 etc from a single row - not up to snuff from my research on a proper algorithm for this.

Thank you for the reply though.

Comment: As long as you don't place some sample data here, it's hard to say. Take 2, 3 "easy" lines and then some lines that are causing problems.

Comment: @hakre Yes my sample data was a bit much, thank you for a sound methodology for presenting sample data - that hurts a lot of my questions. I am revising now. Thx.

Comment: @cerd: I was not able to locate *any* sample data in your question I must admit. Please make it visible what is sample data and what is your database structure.

Comment: @hakre, I placed in the pipe delimited raw and desired output format using your recommended extract (2-3 lines standard raw, plus other outlier type data) note that various tags occur in the right most field more than once and due to the data received they show no pattern of organization.

Comment: And the input? Where is the input?

Comment: @hakre the input is a pipe-delim file: extract of which is shown under: ### SAMPLE DATA ###

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18512/discussion-between-cerd-and-hakre)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the Perl method. Save the code below as parser.pl. Run it as `perl parser.pl data.csv` where data.csv is the name of your data file. (Or make it executable and run `./parser.pl data.csv`.)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

# Take in the first arguement as the file
my $file = $ARGV[0];

# open a filehandle
open (my $fh, '<', $file);

# Well predefine a hashref
my $products = {};

# Loop through the file
while (<$fh>) {

        # remove line breaks
        chomp;

        # split into our primary sections
        my ($id, $product, $csv) = split(/\|/);

        # skip a header line
        next if ($id =~ /\D/);

        # remove the quotes
        ($csv) = ($csv =~ /"(.*)"/);

        # split the CSV an a comma possibly followed by a space
        my @items = split(/,\s*/, $csv);

        # loop through each item in the csv
        foreach my $item(@items) {

                # Our keys and values are reversed!
                my ($value,$key) = ($item =~ /(.*)\[(.*)\]/);

                # Remove trailing whitespace
                $value =~ s/\s+$//;

                # If the arrayref does not exist then create it
                # Otherwise add to it
                if (!exists($products->{$key}->{$product})) {
                        $products->{$key}->{$product} = [$value];
                } else {
                        push(@{$products->{$key}->{$product}}, $value);
                }

        }

}

# We have a nicely formed hashref now. Loop through and print how we want

foreach my $key(keys %$products) {

        # Header for this section
        print "PRODUCT|$key\n";

        # Go through each product and print the different values
        foreach my $product(keys %{$products->{$key}}) {

                while (my $value = shift(@{$products->{$key}->{$product}})) {
                        print "$product|$value\n";
                }

        }

        # Add a space to divide the groups cleanly
        print "\n";

}
```

Sample Output:

```
PRODUCT|MoA
Prod123|Minoxidistuff
Prod125|Direct

PRODUCT|Chem
Prod127|Minoxidistuff
Prod124|Minoxion

PRODUCT|PE
Prod123|Direct
Prod124|Delayed
Prod126|Competitor

PRODUCT|EPC
Prod123|Agonists
Prod124|InterferonA
Prod126|Progestin
Prod126|Agonists
Prod125|Anotherion
Prod125|Agonists
```

Comment: Many thanks - sometimes I forget to fall back on my days of perl and how simple manipulating data can be with it. Thanks again.